# I need some recommendation about Hotspots wifi business

Tags: wireless, network-access

I need  some recommendation about Hotspots wifi business.

I'm planning to start Internet Hotspot wifi business  sealing internet cards. But before I make my first step I want  to know the right equipment and software to run this business because I want to be the best in the market I tried to use one of the wifi hotspots in my area but it's to slow. I did a scan to find out how users are using this hotspot . There was 50 users.  I found out that the hotspot owner did not put a rule to split bandwidth between users.

I want to know is there an access point that can cover 10 kilometres. And is the best system that can control users bandwidth.

Please share your ideas.

Thank you.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Wi-Fi is two-way, so if you had a WAP that could cover 10 km, the clients could still only use it within 100 meters (the IEEE 802.11 maximum distance) because the client radios will only work that far.

Since the airwaves are a shared medium using CSMA-CA, you can't evenly divide the bandwidth among Wi-Fi clients for a first come, first served medium.

I think you need to do some research about IEEE 802.11, how it works, and the laws surrounding the use of unlicensed radio, before you do anything else. This is a subject far too broad to be discussed here, and product or resource recommendations are specifically off-topic.

Comment: So what do you recommend

Comment: As I wrote, product and resource recommendations are specifically off-topic. From http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic Off-Topic, "_product or resource recommendations_"

Answer (score 0):

Wi-Fi hot spots are cheap to set up, but the billing systems can easily cost 10 times as much as a basic hot spot.   Also add in the cost of selling the cards etc.

Hence in the UK, companies that have tried to charge for access to hotspots have not done well, as providing a free hotspot and just letting everyone within range use it, gives a good return on investment for cafes etc, just due to selling more cups of coffee.

Comment: So it's not a good  idea to start hotspot business?